How to fix 'itext' & 'sqlite3' vulnerable issue in Gerserver 2.25.x
While we scan with our internal tool, which warns some severe vulnerabilities on the components of 'itext' and 'sqlite3'. I feel there is some issue in *.jar, *.so, & *.dll files.
Here is few CVE data with NVD link.
Vulnerabilities:

itext - CVE-2021-43113
sqlite3 - CVE-2023-7104

Can anyone help on this to fix?

First read the responsible disclosure guidelines, then follow them. It's also worth checking the release notes to see if they have been addressed or deemed not to apply
